# javascript prompt failing after one try

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am creating a simple bootstrap page where when you first open the page the page asks you do you prefer a dark theme or a light theme (the theme changes based on your answer.) Additionally I want to have it where if the user types anything other than DARK or LIGHT the prompt just keeps asking until you chose a or b. Unfortunately, what happens is the prompt asks the user and you type anything else in and it asks you again, then if you type anything else but the two answers it gives up and resorts to the default background. Is there a way to prevent this? here is my code....

```
var background_image = prompt("Do you prefer a LIGHT background or a DARK background?")


if (background_image == 'LIGHT') {
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/background.jpg")')
} else if (background_image == 'DARK'){
  $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/dark.jpg")')
} else {
  var background_image = prompt("Do you prefer a LIGHT background or a      
  DARK background?")
} 




body{
 background-image: url("../assets/grey.jpg");
}
```

ALSO, if you type anything but a or b the first time then try to correct yourself by typing in light or dark on the 2nd try it automatically reverts to the default theme

Thank you

Comment: If that's for school than ok. Otherwise think again about your idea... Don't let user type expected responses. Create two buttons instead.

Comment: If you feel 50% evil, than at least use `prompt("bla").toLowerCase()` and than compare with `"light"` / `"dark"` (lowercase). Any way... totally bad idea :)

Comment: Also, Logic, if you have two templates only, you could use `confirm` instead of `prompt` like: `confirm("Do you want to see a light theme?")` and the user will have OK and CANCEL. Logically CANCEL will keep the dark theme. Any way... :) yuck

Comment: Haha, @RokoC.Buljan, I believe you made OP quit the development on this! :D

Comment: @Shomz ;) hope not :) wish all the best to Matthew

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code ends after the second prompt, why would you expect it to run one more time.

You need to make it do so - try making it a function, and rerun the function instead of the 2nd prompt. Learn about recursion.

See this:

```js
function ask() {
  var background_image = prompt("Do you prefer a LIGHT background or a DARK background?");

  if (background_image == 'LIGHT') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/background.jpg")')
  } else if (background_image == 'DARK') {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/dark.jpg")')
  } else {
    ask();
  }
}

ask();
```

> ALSO, if you type anything but a or b the first time then try to correct yourself by typing in light or dark on the 2nd try it automatically reverts to the default theme

Again, the 2nd try in your code is irrelevant as nothing happens after it.

Answer (score 1):

You may try loop:

```js
 var quit;
 var user; // for user input
 do {
   quit = true;
   user = prompt('Do you prefer a LIGHT background or a DARK background?', 'LIGHT').toLowerCase();
   if (user === 'light') {
     $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/background.jpg")');
   } else if (user == 'dark') {
     $('body').css('background-image', 'url("assets/dark.jpg")');
   } else {
     quit = false;
   }
 } while (!quit);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

<sup>***Disclaimer***: Not exactly related to the issue that has already a bunch of answers here on SO.</sup>

But related to my comments in your Question, I'd not use alert, confirm, prompt etc at all:

***All it takes:***

```js
var themes = {
  default : "http://placehold.it/800x600/ccc/457?text=MS+THEMES",
  dark    : "http://placehold.it/800x600/125/adc?text=DARK",
  light   : "http://placehold.it/800x600/adc/125?text=LIGHT",
};

$("#dark, #light, #default").click(function(){
    $("body").css({ backgroundImage : "url("+ themes[this.id] +")" });
    $("#popup, #default").fadeToggle();
});
```

```css
html, body{
  margin:0; 
  height:100%;
}
body{
  font:100%/1.2 sans-serif;
  background: url(http://placehold.it/800x600/ccc/457?text=MS+THEMES) 50% / cover;
}
#popup{
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%; top:  50%;
  transform:  translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
  padding:    20px 30px;
  background:rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
  box-shadow:0 5px 30px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#popup h2{
  font-weight: normal;
}
#default{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="default">CHANGE THEME</button>

<div id="popup">
  <p>
    Select your theme:<br><br>
    <button id="dark">DARK</button>
    <button id="light">LIGHT</button>
  </p>
</div>
```